# How to use react-multi-carousel with typescript

Tags: react-multi-carousel

I need a component exactly like below picture.
[image: react-multi-carousel With infinite mode]

image code is [here](https://w3js.com/react-multi-carousel) but i need that codes for typescript.
and also copy codes not working!
any body can help with an example in https://codesandbox.io/.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Recently I used react-multi-carousel with typescript.

Maybe that carousel's parent style is like this.

`display: flex;`

**Carousel** doesn't work with that style so you should change the parent style.
It's not a problem caused by Typescript

`display: block` or add this style.

`min-width: 400px; max-width: 400px;`

it works for me.

Comment: thanks @honey. now i'm using "react-slick" package

Comment: you are welcome @marine727. "react-slick" supports SSR? or custom dot with render outside?

Comment: yeah it's support SSR. can change dot. ------> https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/append-dots